# java - server stops accepting connections after a while

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple multi-client java server on a WinServer 2008 machine and it's working fine, but after a seemingly random ammount of time (days) the server stops accepting any connections and i can't figure out why.

It doesn't catch any exceptions, it doesn't crash, it just doesn't accept any connections, i thought it was the serversocket being GC'd so i made it global but to no avail. It does not seem to be TCP exhaustion either, since there hasn't been anyone connected for hours and it still doesn't accept any connections and i also have set the setReuseAddress to true but it keeps doing the same thing.

The only way to make it work again is to reboot the java server application (doesn't need to reboot the machine) and it's working fine again...for a while.

here's my code relevant to the situation:

```
        try
    {
        ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        while (isAlive)
        {
            Socket skt = srvr.accept();

            this.bw = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
            this.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
            String msg = br.readLine();

                            //process msg

            skt.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

edit: changed code

```
            while (isAlive)
        {
            Socket skt = srvr.accept();
            skt.setSoTimeout(10000);

            acceptConnection(skt);
        }

public void acceptConnection(final Socket skt) throws Exception
{
    Thread discConn = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
                String msg = br.readLine();
//process msg
                }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
            {
                //
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                //
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    skt.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
            }
            }
    };
    discConn.start();
```

Comment: It is better to look at TCP/IP logs and packets.Try to sniff it during this time to investigate what happens to your TCP/IP packets using a sniffer.

Comment: @UVM I don't see anything about this problem that requires sniffing the network.

Comment: @EJP, I posted my comments before he had posted the code.So I could not get a chance to look at his code really

Comment: @DarkW, did you ever figure out the cause of this issue? I have a very similar issue, except that there seems to be no `accept()` after one minute, regardless on how many connections. Sockets are read in different thread, have timeouts, and are closed. =/

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking on client I/O in the accept loop. One client that never sends anything can stop the whole system. All you should do in the accept loop is accept connections and start threads. The only blocking operation should be the accept() itself. Client I/O should be done in a separate thread.

Comment: thanks, yeah, thats what i did on the changed code, it accepts the connections, sets the timeout to 10s and sends the socket to a new thread which handles the socket and the I/O. If the client doesn't send anything within 10s it gives timeout exception and closes the socket.

Answer (score 0):

You're leaking sockets. Your close would be skipped by an exception. Use a finally block to release resources.

```
while(...) {
   Socket sckt;
   try {
      sckt = ...
      ...
   } catch(Exception e) {
   } finally {
       sckt.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: the main thread waits at the socketserver.accept() until a client connects, recieves the information, replies, closes the socket and returns to the socketserver.accept(). Now that i think of it might be it gets stuck at the .readLine() if there's a client that connects and doesn't send anything...even tho it would timeout and give socketTimeoutException after 30 seconds or so.

Comment: You could check for open sockets (don't known if that can be done on windows) when the server becomes unresponsive. Btw, your design isn't really multiclient since it can only handle one client at a time.

Comment: thanks for the help, i've changed the code a bit in order to be more responsive.