# @Java/Android Socket failed to read message

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have trouble with the Java Sockets.

I need to connect a server and a client through the local network and as there can be more then two devices connected to the router the Client must find out the Address of the server.

The only way I know to solve this problem is to get the three first numbers of the clients IP(v4)-address and loop every of the 254 other possible IPs.
*(I know that this way is very slow and may cause many problems. If you know an alternative, I will be glad)*.

Actually the client is an android smartphone so I can get the DHCP-Info.

The problem is, that the read command to check if a device is a server will last forever.

If you need some code, here it is!
code:
onCreate:

```
    final WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) super.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    final DhcpInfo dhcp = manager.getDhcpInfo();
    final String address = intToIp(dhcp.ipAddress);
    String addresspart=address.substring(0, address.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> l = null;
    Log.d("Keyboard","initiating search");
    try {
        l = new checkConnections().execute(addresspart).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

checkConnections:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> l=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for(int i=1;i<=255;i++){
        try {
            worksocket=new Socket(addresspart[0]+i,61927);
            workout=new BufferedOutputStream(worksocket.getOutputStream());
            workin=new BufferedInputStream(worksocket.getInputStream());
            byte[] buffer=new byte[6];
            workin.read(buffer);//at this point the app freezes until you stop the serverside program
            String answer=new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
            Log.i("Keyboard","Welcome Message: "+answer);
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("sdk on")){
                HashMap<String,String> hm=new HashMap<String,String>();
                hm.put("address",addresspart[0]+i);
                l.add(hm);
                workout.write(intToBytes(8));
                workout.write("closing".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                worksocket.close();
                continue;
            }
            else{
                Log.d("Keyboard","No SDK-Programm detected");
                worksocket.close();
                continue;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d("Keyboard",addresspart[0]+i+" doesn't exists");
            continue;
        } catch ( InterruptedIOException e){
            Log.w("System.warn",e.getCause()+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Log.d("Keyboard","timeout");
            continue;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Keyboard",addresspart[0]+i+" doesn't exists");
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        }
        }
        return l;
```

the server's code:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(61927);
        System.out.println("Socket initiated");
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        BufferedInputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream out=new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("client found");
        byte[] buffer=new byte[11];
        out.write("sdk on".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        in.read(buffer);
        String s=new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
        if(!s.equals("got info")){
            System.out.println("No SDK Client");
            client.close();
            serverSocket.close();
            new Main();
    }
```

Comment: Bro, you need to make sure your server sends/receives something in a run loop...

Comment: Refer to tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/index.html on how to create a server in Java (applicable to Android as well as long as you know which Java classes are available on Android)

Comment: I know about multithreading, but I want the server to accept only one client at once. It should be a keyboard app where the PC is the server and it would be counterproductive to have more than one keyboard.

Comment: You can set a reference count to block next `serverSocket.accept()` attempt

Comment: Again `accept()` is a blocking event. Make sure to handle any `accept()` attempt in a separate thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274551/java-server-stops-accepting-connections-after-a-while and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771360/java-socket-server-only-accepts-one-request-then-stops-accepting?rq=1

Comment: More on blocking methods http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/what-is-blocking-methods-in-java-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, I think I should ping the Broadcast-IP and listen for answers instead...
Android's Linux runtime allows it to read from which IP an answer is coming.